# What line of code I could add to vimrc to make <leader>ig command run when vim starts?

Tags: vim

I'm new to Vim, sorry for this newbie question. I'm using a vim plugin [vim-indent-guides](https://github.com/nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides)

The default mapping to toggle the plugin is `<leader>ig`. What modification should be made to make it toggled on when vim-started

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like something the plugin might support in its configuration.
Vim plugins are generally configured by putting something like

```
let g:global_variable_for_plugin = 1
```

in your `~/.vimrc`.

Lo and behold, from the vim-indent-guides documentation:

```
Use this option to control whether the plugin is enabled on Vim startup.

Default: 0. Values: 0 or 1.
>
  let g:indent_guides_enable_on_vim_startup = 0
<
```

Answer (score 4):

What you need is to run the following command at vim startup

```
:IndentGuidesEnable
```

One of the ways is to add an autocommand to your .vimrc like

```
au VimEnter * IndentGuidesEnable
```

There are probably other ways but this looks pretty simple for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why that plugin is not enabled by default but the

```
IndentGuidesEnable
```

command seems to do just that. Add it somewhere in your `~/.vimrc`.

More generally, mappings are just convenient shortcuts for commands or sequences of commands. You want to execute the command, not the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is question is long ago but just an update. The selected answer doesn't work on Neovim. To fix that, add this in .vimrc:

`autocmd VimEnter * :IndentGuidesEnable`